# Use Configuration File To Specify Connection String To Define a Data Source in Unit Test for Data Driven Test CSV

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, datasource, app-config, mstest

The following code is defined in the test class. But i want to use DataSource("DataSourceSettingName") and app.config define.

```
<DeploymentItem("DataSets\\TestUserMainInput.csv")>
<DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", "|DataDirectory|\\DataSets\\TestUserMainInput.csv", "TestUserMainInput#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)>
```

1. Environment:

   - Visual Studio 2017
   - Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting
   - .NET Framework 4.6.1

I already tried the following code. It failed.

```
<configSections>
    <section name="microsoft.visualstudio.testtools" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestConfigurationSection, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyExcelConn" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DataSets\TestUserMainInput.csv;Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited'" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <microsoft.visualstudio.testtools>
    <dataSources>
      <add name="MainDataSource" connectionString="MyExcelConn" dataTableName="TestUserMainInput#csv" dataAccessMethod="Sequential"/>
    </dataSources>
  </microsoft.visualstudio.testtools>
```

Output --> Tests 
Error Message

```
An exception occurred while calling the 'executor: // mstestadapter / v2' player: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.MSTestSettings, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter, Version = 14.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken The species could not be resolved for = b03f5f7f11d50a3a '.
```

Could anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to change the app.config

Just Create a new test project and add a class like this one.
The test iterates for all the csv rows. You need to place the csv in your solution and change it to copy local always.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

    private static TestContext _testContext;

    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void SetupTests(TestContext testContext)
    {
        _testContext = testContext;
    }

    [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", "|DataDirectory|\\DataSource\\teste.csv", "teste#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), DeploymentItem("DataSource\\teste.csv"), TestMethod]
    public void Testing()
    {
            Assert.AreEqual(TestContext.DataRow["user"], "myusername");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in following thread:

https://dondeetan.com/2017/07/03/referencing-mstest-and-mstestv2-unit-testing-framework-through-namespace-aliasing/

MSTest (Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll) and MSTestV2 (Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll) those assemblies have the exact same namespace.

The Issue: Reference both MSTest and MSTestV2 in the same test project using the C# but that there's no VB way of doing this.